# How to stop Android Studio notifying update for uninstalled package?

Tags: android-studio, android-studio-2.1

Android studio keeps showing the following update:

[image]

I do not have this package installed and **I do not want to** because it requires stopping HyperV that I need.

[image]

Could anyone offer a tip on this?

Answer (score -1):

**Enabling and Disabling Plugins**

> 1. Open the Settings dialog (e.g. Ctrl+Alt+S).
> 2. In the left-hand pane, select Plugins.
> 3. On the Plugins page that opens in the right-hand part of the dialog, do one of the following:    --> To enable a plugin, select the check box to the right of its name.    --> To disable a plugin, clear
>      the corresponding check box.
> 4. If the plugin of interest is not present in the list (which may be the case for a repository plugin), download and install the plugin.
> 5. Restart IntelliJ IDEA for the changes to take effect.

[image]

visit [managing plugin](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/managing-plugins.html) for more details.

Comment: Thank you for lending a hand.  I followed your instructions, but could not figure out which one I should disable.  Could you offer a tip on this?

Comment: If you want to disable Google package than uncheck all Google's plugin than try.

Comment: No, I do not want to disable all of them.  I just want to disable the one related to the uninstalled package: Google API System Image.